# Python scale GeoJSON by absolute value in meters

Tags: python, geojson, shapely, affinity

I am trying to generate a python code that takes geojson containing polygon as input an then outputs a polygon that is scaled by exact value in meters. For example lets say that my polygon is a square representing a house and I want to get an output of another square that is exactly 20m bigger on each side. This would be simple with square but it is quite hard with complex shapes.

Heres is what I use now (found here [Scale GeoJSON to find latitude and longitude points nearby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66369801/scale-geojson-to-find-latitude-and-longitude-points-nearby)):

```
import json
from shapely import affinity
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point, mapping

def handler(event, context):
    with open('polygon.geojson', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        js = json.load(f)
    polygon = shape(js['features'][0]['geometry'])
    polygon_nearby = affinity.scale(polygon, xfact=1.1, yfact=1.1)
    print(json.dumps({"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", 'properties': {}, 'geometry': mapping(polygon)}]}))
    print(json.dumps({"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", 'properties': {}, 'geometry': mapping(polygon_nearby)}]}))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    handler(None, None)
```

However as you can see this scales by realtive value (10%) and I would like to change that to absolute value in meters.

Thank you in forward for any suggestions